# Optimization with unvariant polymorphic type inside a loop

Tags: c++, dynamic, c++11, dynamic-cast, dynamic-dispatch

I have an expensive `for` loop that is taking more time than it should due to dynamic casting overhead *inside* the loop.

An example code would be the following (compilable)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct DerivedA : Base {};
struct DerivedB : Base {};

struct Calculator {
  virtual void proceed(const DerivedA& ) const  {
    std::cout << "doing A stuff" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void proceed(const DerivedB& ) const  {
    std::cout << "doing B stuff" << std::endl;
  }
};

void doStuff(const std::shared_ptr<Base> &base_ptr) {
  Calculator calc;
  // Code that does stuff using only Base properties
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { // expensive loop
    // "redundant" dynamic cast at every iteration
    auto a_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedA>(base_ptr);
    if(a_ptr) calc.proceed(*a_ptr);
    auto b_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedB>(base_ptr);
    if(b_ptr) calc.proceed(*b_ptr);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Base> base_ptr = std::make_shared<DerivedA>();
  doStuff(base_ptr);
}
```

Since the class is not changing inside the function, I think that there has to be a way to avoid the polymorhpism overhead (and branching) inside the loop and perform a *single* dynamic cast and a single function call without having to write the loop multiple times.

What I considered:

1. **Cast inside the `proceed` call.**
2. **Visitor pattern.**

I don't think that any of them solves the problem. Those are just different ways of doing the same thing.

I'm considering to rethink my design, but before that I would be happy to hear any ideas and suggestions that you may have to improve this piece of code.

Comment: Is there reason not to have an abstract proceed method on base, and implement it differently in the 2 derived classes? Then there's no need for the explicit dynamic cast - it'll just be a normal vtable lookup.

Comment: @mfontanini what are the advantadges of going with double dispatching? I don't see them.

Comment: @FKaria nevermind. I was focusing on the design, rather than the possible optimizations.

Comment: @Baldrick Yes, I realize that the polymorphism has been implemented in the other way around. This is what I'm considering to do now. Before I wanted to ask for other ideas.

Comment: @FKaria: I think in your case 'standard C++ polymorphism' (as described above) is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I do not see why a const ref to a shared_ptr is needed. I do not see why dynamic_pointer_cast is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would rather do as Baldrick suggests in a comment to the OP then I would try the other alternatives cited in the OP. I would everytime profiling/mesuring the results to make an informed decision.

If you are not yet satisfied, then I suggest something along these lines:

```
template <typename T>
void doStuffImpl(const T &obj) {
    Calculator calc;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        calc.proceed(obj);
}

void doStuff(const std::shared_ptr<Base> &base_ptr) {

    auto a_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedA>(base_ptr);
    if (a_ptr)
        doStuffImpl(*a_ptr);

    auto b_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedB>(base_ptr);
    if (b_ptr)
        doStuffImpl(*b_ptr);
}
```

Comment: You could also have `doStuffImpl` take a pointer (possibly null) and directly pass the result of `dynamic_pointer_cast` without a temporary variable (slightly neater).

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to think to do something with templates and I couldn't come up with something clear. I will try first C++ standard polymorphism and then maybe this. I thing that now I have a cler view of all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to optimize if you know your data.

If you know that your data contains mostly type A, then make sure this will be the first statement in your if list of your iteration. I am not sure though, if this is possible with dynamic objects.

Maybe you can exclude some calls to be iterated by using if-then-else statement inside the iteration? Is it really necessary to do always both dynamic pointer casts (a_ptr, b_ptr), or can there be exceptions reducing the workload?

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate your types of derived class and so avoid the double-dispatch - implement some `GetClass()` as a pure virtual on `Base`

```
void doStuff(const std::shared_ptr<Base> &base_ptr) {
Calculator calc;
// Code that does stuff using only Base properties
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { // expensive loop

  switch(base_ptr->GetClass())
  {
    case TYPE_A:
    // "redundant" dynamic cast at every iteration
    auto a_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedA>(base_ptr);
    if(a_ptr) 
      calc.proceed(*a_ptr);
    break;

    case TYPE_B:
    auto b_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedB>(base_ptr);
    if(b_ptr)
      calc.proceed(*b_ptr);
    break;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Base> base_ptr = std::make_shared<DerivedA>();
  doStuff(base_ptr);
}
```